# Finding clusters of similar nodes with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a set of hundred of thousands of nodes with like relationship, (Foodie) -likes-> (Food), I would like to find out logical cluster of Foodie nodes.

For instance suppose I want to divide the cluster into two sets. As an output I would like two sets which have the most common eating habits.

The same logic can be extended to 3,4,5 sets etc. In case of three sets, each set would have most like eating habits. Please note that sets may NOT have same number of nodes.

An application for instance could be coloring of nodes. If the foodies were of different countries, the color of the nodes could point to various countries assuming the people of different countries ate similar food.

I would like to write a Cypher query to extract the nodes. I am stumped as where to start. Any solution or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

what about trying the current milestone of Neo4J 2.0 (http://www.neo4j.org/download, milestone section) and assigning your nodes different labels according to their characteristics (http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels)?

Then, you'll only have to Cypher execute queries like:

```
MATCH (nodes:MY_LABEL)
WHERE /.../
RETURN nodes
```

so that you can retrieve nodes by clusters.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Cliques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29). This is a general Graph Theory idea, but it sounds like what you want is to define certain 'cliques' of foodies, say there are BBQ foodies, Food Truck foodies, etc.

Comment: Hi Nicholas. I think you are right. This may very well be a clique problem. I wasn't attempting to find all cliques but perhaps top few ones. I was hoping if I were to divide the graph only in say 2 sets, there would be a simpler way to find out which node went to which set.

Comment: If you use two graphs, yes it is easier, but you lose the ability to reuse the graph. It may also be easiest to define a node for different food lovers and have that relate to the user, instead of properties.